# CanCan and sets of data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, cancan

I've been struggling through this for some time and I've finally got to the point where it seems that CanCan doesn't allow you to authorize a collection of records.  For example:

ads_controller.rb

```
def index
    @ads = Ad.where("ads.published_at >= ?", 30.days.ago).order("ads.published_at DESC")
    authorize! :read, @ads
end
```

ability.rb

```
def initialize(user)
  user ||= User.new # Guest user

  if user
    if user.role? :admin  # Logged in as admin
      can :manage, :all
    else                  # Logged in as general user
      can :read, Ad
      can :read_own, Ad, :user_id => user.id
      can :create, Ad
    end
  else                    # Not logged in (Guest)
    can :read, Ad
  end
end
```

This results the unauthorised access message when trying to access the index action.

```
You are not authorized to access this page.
```

However, if you change the authorize call in the index action to check on the Ad class rather than the collection like so

```
def index
    @ads = Ad.where("ads.published_at >= ?", 30.days.ago)
    authorize! :read, Ad
end
```

... it works fine.

Any help in explaining this one would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

ps.  I was originally getting redirect loops when trying to work this out.  It turns out there's a gotchya with the recommended rescue_from that you put in the application controller to give you nice error messages.  If your root_path is set to the same place where your authorize! call is not true (or failing), you'll get a redirect loop.  Comment out the rescue_from  Learnt that one the hard way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CanCan is not designed to be used like that. You can check whether a user has permissions on the model class (e.g. `Ad`) or a single instance (e.g. `@ad`).

I suggest you just use `accessible_by` to filter your collection:

```
@ads = Ad.where("ads.published_at >= ?", 30.days.ago).accessible_by(current_ability) 
# @ads will be empty if none are accessible by current user

raise CanCan::AccessDenied if @ads.empty?  # handle however you like
```

Another approach would be to define a custom permission based on the conditions you use to retrieve the collection:

```
# ability.rb
can :read_ads_from_past_month, Ad, ["ads.published_at >= ?", 30.days.ago]

# in your controller
def index
  authorize! :read_ads_from_past_month, Ad
  @ads = Ad.where("ads.published_at >= ?", 30.days.ago)
end
```

Comment: Thanks bowsersenior.  I was trying something similar to your second option but couldn't make it work - I think it was conceptual in the use of the class (Ad).  I'll give it another go.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem usings splats. In this code example, I am trying to authorize users on a collection of `TimeOffRequests`. They should be authorized if the User is an admin, a manager or the time off request belongs to them.

```
# time_off_requests_controller.rb
authorize! :read, *@time_off_requests

# Ability.rb
can :manage, TimeOffRequest do |*time_off_requests|
  membership.has_any_role?(:admin, :manager) ||
    time_off_requests.all? { |tor| membership.id == tor.employee_id }
end
```

I wrote about it in detail here if you're interested: http://zacstewart.com/2012/01/08/defining-abilities-for-collections-of-records-using-cancan.html